# Disable headers on particular request HttpClient angular 5?

Tags: httpclient, angular5

I have upgraded my app from ng4 to ng5 v-5.2.9. I have set the headers for every request. But on my app some request does not support headers, so how to disable headers from particular request not every request.

Previously with ng4 I was using http but now facing issues as its not supported any more in ng5

**setHeader.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

 @Injectable()
 export class AddHeaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
     intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        request = request.clone({
            setHeaders: { 
                Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`,
                Ip:currentUser.Ip
            }
        });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
}
}
```

**app.module.ts:-**

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
   providers: [{
   provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
   useClass: AddHeaderInterceptor,
   multi: true,
  }],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Basically headers are used for token and for autorization nut some of the API doesn't need to be authorized and hence headers are not required, by using setHeader it applies to all api calls. I have got **HttpErrorResponse** on my browser console. where its not required

Thanks!